# Is there a way to use 'Geo-polygon' query inside elasticsearch ingest pipeline?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, pipeline, elastic-stack

I want to use the elasticsearch Geo-polygon query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-polygon-query.html) or Geo-shape query inside an ingest pipeline and I've been thinking how to do it - as there is no such processor as `query processor` and the example for the geo polygon is with this type of query.

The reason for me trying to use this tool is to enrich documents which's country location is `null`, by checking their `lat` and `lon` fields and determining which country the doc is from.

Is there anyway this could be done in an ingest pipeline?
Or any other way to determine a position by lat and lon within geo shapes in a pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for enrichment of the data with geo-based policy: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/geo-polygon-query-inside-ingest-pipeline/274886/9

Also note that there is a feature suggestion pending in Elastic Github in order to exclude the geo-shape used for the enrichment, so there will be no need for a second pipeline to delete the field.